# Adding Custom Pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code, so I am building a Wordpress theme to make some experiments and see how everything works from the practice.

I installed wordpress locally and I a made a Child Theme. Now to start designing my new theme I started watching how the wordpress structure works and there is something that I don't understand:

I am making my portfolio, and I have some sections (Paintings, Films and Photography). And each section has a subcategory.

It means that each section is a page and each subcategory is a post? Or each section is a page and each category is a page too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your subcategories as subpages for to other pages. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Go to Administration > Pages > Add New panel.
2. In the right menu, click the "Page Parent" drop-down menu.
3. The drop-down menu contains a list of all the Pages already created for your site.
4. Select the appropriate parent Page from the drop-down menu to make the current Page a child Page.
5. Add content to the subpage.
6. Click Publish when ready.

More information on pages here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Comment: and is it possible to add a group of pages in a category and not inside a parent page?

Comment: don't think you can do that by default, but there's a plugin to add tags/categories for pages like you would do for regular posts: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-tags-and-categories-for-pages/